# App crash when calling Alertdialog from another class

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

the weird thing is that the app crash only when I build it , but if I run it from android studio the alert works fine .

**Here is the non activity Class**

```
public class Rateapp {

public static void onexit(Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle("Are you sure to Exit ?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alert.create().show();
}
```

}

Now I want to call the onexit method from onBackPressed in the mainActivity

```
public class first_java extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Rateapp.onexit(this);
    }
    }
```

I don't know if this will alsp help , but here is the styles.xml anyway

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

**EDIT : I found out that when proguard is activated the app crash , and if not it works good , what should I do ?**

Comment: post the error log

Comment: when can I get  the error ? the app crash only after I build it but works correctly when I run it from android studio

Comment: `Rateapp.onexit(first_java.this);`

Comment: how can app crash when you are building?

Comment: I mean after I generate the signed Apk and test it , it crash when I press Back

Comment: guys I realise that proguard is the problem

Comment: when proguard is activated the app crash , what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proguard removes few classes if they are not explicitly set as

-keepclassmembers ....

Add these and check if it is still crashing

```
keep class  android.content.** { *; }
keep class  android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm if you were able to install app on device and on launching app it crashed? If yes then you might have received error log could you paste it here.

Comment: I just realise that the problem is coming from Proguard , the backpressed method crash when Proguard activation is true . else , the app works fine , the problem is only when I call onBackPressed while PROGUARD is activated

Answer (score 0):

- Add this `super.onBackPressed();` you'have to add this

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
      Rateapp.onexit(getApplicationContext());
  }
  ```